# Commits not uploaded to codecov

Tags: python, continuous-integration, automated-tests, travis-ci, codecov

I have a python proyect on github named [codecovtest](https://github.com/raczben/codecovtest).

I have the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/raczben/codecovtest/blob/master/.travis.yml) file, which starts automatic test on travis-ci, on each push on github.

The test passed on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/raczben/codecovtest/jobs/536675331).

**But the coverage report isn't uploaded to [codecov](https://codecov.io/gh/raczben/codecovtest/commits).**

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `codecov` command with the codecov.io's bash script int the `.travis.yml`

```
# Push the results back to codecov
after_success:
- bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```